# How to wait for an iframe to be fully loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, ionic-framework, iframe

I want to measure the iframe load time

I tried using async-await but this doesn't work

```
mesureLoadTime = async function()
{
this.StartTime = new Date().getTime();
this.content = await this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl('https://www.example.com')
this.EndTime = new Date().getTime();
this.loadTime = (this.EndTime - this.StartTime)/ 1000
}
```

Comment: `<iframe ... (load)="someFunction()"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

Check [console.time](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/time) if that's what you're looking for